# GooglePlusUtil cannot be resolved (Android)

Tags: android, compilation

I have an Android 2.2 targeted library project, whose `MyLibraryGooglePlusSocialPlugin.java` has a `import com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil;` being failed to compile (`GooglePlusUtil cannot be resolved`), while others are okay:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusShare;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer;
```

I've updated the related Google services through Android SDK manager today, and set the build path and dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

The GooglePlusUtils class has been removed because you no longer need it. All of the existing error handling functionality has been integrated in a way that doesn't require developer intervention.

As an example of how you can migrate from using this (now deprecated) class, see the following change from the Google+ Photohunt Android client sample that resolves the issue:

https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-photohunt-client-android/commit/090c22b4721fde6859361aca210823822c218da8

Comment: should we simply omit the GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp calls as shown in step 5 here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share#adding_interactive_posts and just use the code in the if block?

Comment: Yes, I will try and write an example of what you need to change.

Comment: Thanks! I will update my code. We need more examples of what we can do with G+ integration in an Android app.

Comment: 404 from link. Bad link (

Answer (score 1):

Their documentation has not changed online, but it is indeed missing form the jar. I would look for a copy of the last version and use it for the time being.

** UPDATE **
You can do the same things with the GooglePlayServicesUtil and checking to see if they user has the correct package name for Google Plus.

Answer (score 1):

I work it around by downgrading to a previous version where the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `google-play-services_lib` goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="3159130"
    android:versionName="3.1.59 (744626-30)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

</manifest>
```

---

### UPDATE

I downgrade the library by reloading a lower version that was saved in my local disk. No idea how to downgrade through Android SDK manager.

Answer (score -1):

The old GooglePlusUtil + error codes are not needed now, because even if the device has not installed GooglePlus application, GooglePlay services provides connection to user account. You can only check if GooglePlay services is present and updated using GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable and hide UI field with GooglePlus. In other case connection to user (GooglePlus) account will be made.